# Transfer data from nonfunctional Mac to another Mac with an external drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, external-disk, thunderbolt

I have to save data from a MacBook Air (13" Early 2015) that won't start. I was suggested to buy a Thunderbolt cable, to be able to connect the broken MacBook to another MacBook and see all the data as an external drive.

At this point, instead of transferring all data to the functioning MacBook, can I connect an external drive to the functioning one to transfer all the data from the broken MacBook there?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 2):

Going on the assumption that your MacBook Air won't "start" means it won't turn on I will assume you can't boot into Target Disk Mode.  So, to rephrase your question, *Can you remove the drive from the dead MacBook and connect it to the functioning Mac to transfer the data?*

The answer is **yes.**  You will need to basically do two things:

- Remove the SSD
- Install it into a [USB enclosure](http://radnex.us/mba_ssd_enclosures)

(You didn't specify which MacBook Air you have and it is very important as the drives are very different).

**Removing the SSD**
The procedure for removing the SSD for all MBAs is essentially the same - you remove the back cover, remove the retaining screws of the SSD and disconnect the SSD module.

[image]
[image]

[Ifixt.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+11-Inch+Mid+2013+SSD+Replacement/16842) has excellent instructions and this procedure is rated as "moderate" (no idea why, it's super easy) and only 5-10 mins to complete.

**Install in USB Enclosure**

Next, you install it into the USB enclosure - just plug it in - it only goes in one way.  Reassemble the enclosure and plug in the USB cable and plug it into your Mac.

For the 2015 MBA (per your comments), you will need [this enclosure](http://radnex.us/mba_2013-2017_ssd_enclosure).  The 2010, 2012 and 2013-15 MBA's all use completely different interfaces.  Make sure you select the one that is for your generation MBA.

[image]

You can then mount the drive and transfer your data.

Comment: I have a Macbook Air (13-inch, Early 2015).

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified the exact models of the Macs involved, we can't give you a definite answer.

However, assuming you can...

- start the MacBook Air in [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462)
- connect the MacBook Air to the other MacBook

... then yes you can also connect another external hard drive to the other MacBook and just copy the data from the MacBook Air to the external hard drive without first having to copy the data to the other Macbook.

Put simply, the functioning MacBook will see both the MacBook Air and the external hard drive as two separate drives and you would just be copying data from one drive to the other.

**[EDIT]**

I'm assuming you have a MacBook Air with a Thunderbolt port, but if you don't then Allan's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I have a thunderbolt port, is a Macbook Air 13-inch (Early 2015)