# Reuse a SSD MZ-JPV1280/0A4 as external SSD

Tags: hard-drive, partition, ssd, memory

I have a 128GB SSD Samsung Model MZ-JPV1280/0A4 from my 2015 MacBook Pro Retina and I would like to reuse it in my new PC (ASUS Vivobook Pro, with Core i7 7th Gen, Nvidia GTX 1050, 16GB RAM) where i have done a partition of 50GB for popOS (Ubuntu).

I would like to exploit the power of the SSD as external disk. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

To use any of the Apple SSDs as an external drive, you will need a [USB Enclosure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281763/119271) just as you would for any other drive.  You simply need to ensure that the enclosure is compatible with Apple's SSD interface - check the specs of the enclosure!

That said, given the *extremely* low price point of off-the-shelf SSDs (not proprietary Apple) and the very high prices Apple SSDs fetch on the secondary market (eBay, Gumtree, etc.), you are better off buying a new regular SSD and selling the Apple SSD to someone who needs it for their Apple machine.  You'll likely make a nice profit.