# Looking for external case for SSD from a MacBook Pro 13" 2017 (A1708)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

A friend has an SSD that was removed from a mid-2017 13" MacBook Pro (non Touch Bar, A1708) whose logic board died. She bought a new MacBook Pro, so the 2017 is still nonfunctional. The SSD has data she needs to get. Does anybody offer an external case where this SSD could be installed? "These drives use a proprietary Apple PCIe 3.0 x4 interface with a 22+34 pin connector." (I'm still on a 2014 MacBook Pro, so these newer ones are unfamiliar territory.)

Comment: See this [similar answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281763/119271).  The Air and Pro from 2015 to 2017 used the same proprietary SSD interface. Those enclosures are expensive (and rare).

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is why backups are essential. Relying on one single device is fatal. Your best bet is a specialist Mac shop like OWC; but it won't be cheap.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Unfortunately, the SSD used in the 2016 & 2017 "function keys" 13-inch MacBook Pros (and only in those two models) is an oddball, which won't fit in the cases provided by OWC (among others?) for the blade-type SSDs. You might find this response of interest: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255540719?answerId=260294809022#260294809022.

Comment: It's true that the 2016 to 2020 Intel MBPs were pretty poor -- not helped by hot CPUs. But the new Apple Silicon laptops are some of the best I've ever seen from the company. (Ironically, these days, it's the software that's lacking.) There's nothing to repair, though -- it's a one-piece computer. So, again, you'll need a good backup strategy. I've found TM to be very reliable (across hundreds of Macs that I've been involved with), and it's saved my bacon countless times since 2007.